# Zend Framework 2 Skeleton Layout

Tags: zend-framework, zend-framework2

I am creating a form using Zend Framework 2 and the Skeleton Application.

I want my layout to replicate the default example:

[image]

As you can see above, the form inputs stretch to the width of the screen. The code to produce this is (using just the email address field as an example):

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
    <input type="email" placeholder="Email" id="exampleInputEmail1" class="form-control">
</div>
```

I would like the same result to happen when I add my own form element using Zend Framework 2 (Skeleton application). But when I add an element:

```
$this->add(array(
         'name' => 'campaign_code',
         'type' => 'Text',             
         'options' => array(
             'label' => 'Campaign Code',
         ),
         'attributes' => array(
            'class'  => 'form-control',
         )                
     ));
```

The resulting HTML is:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label>
        <span>Campaign Code</span>
        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="campaign_code">
    </label>
</div>
```

Resulting in:

[image]

Notice how the `label` tag is surrounding the `span` and `input` elements? I don't want that. I want the `label` tag to close itself as in the first `html` example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The form view helpers are so smart while rendering the elements from your form.

> Add an id attribute with respective element

```
 $this->add(array(
     'name' => 'campaign_code',
     'type' => 'Text',             
     'options' => array(
         'label' => 'Campaign Code',
     ),
     'attributes' => array(
        'class'  => 'form-control',
        'id'  => 'your_id',
     )                
 ));
```